# history.replaceState() causing javascript to be printed on page when clicking the back in history button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In a js.erb file I have

```
history.replaceState("posts", "A new title!", "/posts/<%= @post.slug %>");
```

It works great when I call the js.erb file. However, if go to another page than click the back in history button the page prints my jQuery code into text. Anyone know how I can fix this so that it goes to an actual page when I click back.